# Rename for column names in inner Join

Tags: php, mysql, join, inner-join

I have 2 tables like this:

```
Table 'c'

|  id  |  item_1  |   item_2  |
-------------------------------
|  1   |   1      |    2      |
-------------------------------

Table 'i'

|  id  |  name    | 
-------------------
|  1   |   item   |   
-------------------
|  2   |  item_2  |
-------------------
```

No i need to get from table c the result included the names of the items. so i build an inner JOIN for this.

```
SELECT c.*, i.name FROM c 

INNER JOIN i ON 
c.item_1 = i.id 
OR 
c.item_2 = i.id
```

This works "fine". But i get something like this back:

```
   |  id  |  item_1  |   item_2  |  name   |
    ----------------------------------------
    |  1   |   1      |    2      | item_2 |
    ----------------------------------------
```

The problem is clear - i need to get back 2 names for the two item_ids, but only get one. So is it possible to set a new name for the column ? something like this:

```
SELECT c.*, i.name FROM c 

INNER JOIN i ON 
c.item_1 = i.id SET name AS name_1
INNER JOIN i ON 
c.item_2 = i.id SET name AS name_2
```

So the result will be like this:

```
   |  id  |  item_1  |   item_2  |  name_1   |  name_2 |
    ----------------------------------------------------
    |  1   |   1      |    2      | item_1 |  item_2   | 
    ----------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like?

```
SELECT c.*, 
       i1.name as name_1, 
       i2.name as name_2
  FROM c 
  INNER JOIN I as i1 
     ON c.item_1 = i1.id 
  INNER JOIN I as i2 
     ON c.item_2 = i2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

this serves the same

```
SELECT c.*, 
       i1.name as name_1, 
       i1.name as name_2
  FROM c 
  INNER JOIN I as i1 
     ON c.item_1 = i1.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Despite your table design being pretty meh, you can join a table multiple times by using aliases.

```
SELECT c.*, 
       i1.name as name1, 
       i2.name as name2 
FROM (c INNER JOIN i AS i1 ON c.item1=i1.id_i) 
     INNER join i as i2 ON c.item2=i2.id_i
```

But please reconsider the table design, it is a simple 1:n-relationship between c and i!

Comment: This was just a demonstration. In this case i need this tables a relationship table between them makes no sense. This was just a simple demo of the structure. But thanks (: